# Find and replace folder of files - One $file_var with $var value

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to scan through all the files in the folder and replace all instances of $file_X within the file with the variable $X defined in my bash script on my debian 6.0 install.

For example, if the file contains $file_dep I want it to be replaced with the value of the variable $dep defined in my bash script.

Here is an example of my config file:

```
IP address = $file_dep
```

Here is an xample of a definition in my bash script

```
$dep=192.168.0.1
```

Here is the best starting point I could find using google.

```
# Replace Config Values
cd /home/config
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/$szAnswer1/$szAnswer2/g"
```

My pseudo code (im not good with bash)

```
Find $FILE_X
Replace $FILE_X with value $X
```

Can anyone offer me a bit more help?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE_X=old
X=new
find . -name "*$FILE_X*" -exec bash -c 'echo mv $1 ${1//'"$FILE_X"'/'"$X"'}' -- {} \;
```

and if output is ok remove the echo